# RowSimilarityJob and ItemSimilarityJob in mahount pseud-distributed or not?

Tags: hadoop, distributed-computing, mahout

Does somebody know whether the ItemSimilarityJob and RowSimilarityJob in mahout are psedo- or fully distributed jobs? What I mean are they only splitting the input to multiple nodes or are they "true" distributed implementations of the similarity metrics used.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are really distributed, yes.